# ZipCode Database webDevelopment PHP, MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

i just want to ask if is there any API for zipcode database? where we can find the City from the certain zipcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this:

http://www.abbreviations.com/zip_api.asp

Answer (score 1):

[Geocoded zip database](http://www.lustforge.com/2011/07/20/really-free-zipcode-database-download/) updated through July 2011. And I agree to all the above, don't use someone else's zip database via an API when you can use your own!

Comment: Anyone who see this comment and might think (like I did) that this sounds like a sales pitch it's not. This guy compiled a list of zips with longs/lats and is providing it for free on his site. Need more heroes like this!

Comment: @Jeremy I guess it could, apologies. I plan to update it again shortly and put it on Github so others can update/download it. Then it will be clear that it's free.

Comment: Included fields are zip, lat, lon, state, city.

No GIS polygons or multiple cities per zip.

Answer (score 0):

[Try this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zips/) , they have a free database in SQL format. It doesn't have an API but it doesn't limit you to N lookups per day. It also includes geo coordinates as well as the city name and state.

Comment: last update 2005; fields are zip, state, lat, lon, city/state pair.

Doesn't have GIS polygons associated with zips, or multiple cities per zip.

Answer (score 0):

The USPS has an API available.

The details of the api can be checked out as well.

UPDATE
USPS [API page](https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/list-of-apis.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Check [Postal Code Database](http://www.worldcitiesdatabase.com/postal-code-database.aspx) to see if it fits your requirement. Check the online demo first to see it has what you need. Do note that it is a paid service.